# Manage 2 displays remotely

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have a pc with a nVidia Quadro graphic card.

The card has 2 DisplayPort outs where 2 40" Full HD TV are connected.

I need to run 2 separate fullscreen videos, one each display.

The problem is displays are far from the pc station and I cannot control them from there.

I tried with a remote desktop connection but when I connect screen 1 shows login and screen 2 simply blackens (I'm logged off).

The pc, an HP, also has his native graphics card still installed it would be nice if I could connect there a 15" monitor with the desktop on and use the TVs only as secondary where I can send fullscreen videos.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a remote desktop like client is acceptable and you would prefer it free, I would definitely recommend TeamViewer.  It has the option to switch between different displays or show multiple displays at once.  It also has native apps for both iPhone and Android.

Answer (score 0):

If running Windows 7 - then what you are talking about should be possible as long as you have "Extend these displays" selected in your Screen Resolution window. If you are talking about using RDP to connect remotely to this PC to control it and still want to maintain multiple monitor support then the only option is to upgrade the controlling PC to Windows 7 Ultimate, which supports the Multimon setting in RDP.

See this link on Technet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff393699(WS.10).aspx